# Can't browse SVN repo using Android browser

Tags: android, svn, visualsvn

This is kind of an overly-specific issue :) I have an SVN repo on my home server using VisualSVN, latest version. It works perfectly.

The problem I have though is that if I try to browse my repo using any Android web browser, I get a blank page. The URL is right, I've authenticated, and there's no HTTP errors apparent, its just blank.  I've tried a number of browser and have tried setting them to desktop mode, but no good.

It works fine from a desktop, whether on my LAN or from an external location.

Anyone have any ideas? Like I said, its a very specific issue, but I'm just putting it out there in case anyone is familiar with the problem (I spent about 40 minutes Googling, didn't find anything).

Thanks,
Frank

Comment: Are you using https on your SVN server?  Can you post the repository url (you can blank out the middle bits -- I just want to see the protocol, port number, and anything else that is pertinent).  Android is VERY sensitive about SSL certificates, so if you're using https, that could be part of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Since it's on a home server, look through the server logs right after trying to connect with your phone and see if there are any specific errors.

You should also try faking the phone's useragent, maybe it's trying to load a mobile version of the page and that's causing an issue. You can also try faking your desktop useragent to look like a phone and see if it receives any errors.

In general, try to isolate the issue. I had a similar issue a while ago and it turns out that my ISP was blocking port 80, so I set Apache to use 8080 and it worked. But that's probably not your issue since you can connect from an external location.